# anonymize_table appears to convert table names input to lowercase

Tags: postgresql, anonymize

I'm testing out using `anonymize_table(table_name)` via `postgresql-anonymizer` on a database to attempt to anonymise data.

However, when using the command `SELECT anon.anonymize_table('Users')`. It returns the error message: `ERROR:  column "Users" does not exist`

When listing the tables with `/dt`, I see the table in the output as expected.

`public | Users                               | table | postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
SELECT anon.anonymize_table('"Users"');
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you!